# How to disable and preselect an option from a select multiple

Tags: javascript, html, select, disabled-input, multiple-select

I need to disable/hide if possible natively, or with js an option of a multiple type select but keep it selected.
The example below only works if the Select is normal, but when I add the "multiple" attribute it doesn't work the way I want:

Select Normal (the expected result in multiple select):

```
<select>
  <option hidden>Default Hidden</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Select Multiple expected (but don't work):

```
<select multiple>
  <option hidden>Default Hidden</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

I tried using the "disabled" attribute in conjunction with the "selected" attribute as shown below, and it even "works", but the option value that is disabled is still sent on form submit (which was not supposed to happen).

I appreciate any help.

```
<select multiple>
  <option disabled selected>Default Hidden</option>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mister Jojo, but removing an attribute is not the problem, but leaving an option disabled and as a default value pre-selected in select, which is my goal.

Comment: Have you tried disabled without selected?

Comment: Yes, it disables the option, but does not preselect it. I even edited the question title to be clearer.

Comment: Yes, yes, it "works" as said in the description, but the value of this disabled option is still being sent in the form (which should not happen).

Comment: Nice advice @Mister Jojo, I found your last comment to be as helpful as the pause button for the Winrar installation. I don't know everything, which is why I'm here, because I know the Stack Overflow community is amazing at finding creative solutions to the most diverse problems.